# No such file error in JSCH

Tags: java, linux, jsch

I am trying to download a file from a one Linux machine to other Linux machine through Java code, but every time I'm getting an error mentioned below.

```
2: No such file 
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846) 
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2198) 
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2215) 
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:913) 
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:873) 
at custom.lta.app.cron.tms.SFTPBean.downloadFile(SFTPBean.java:73) 
at custom.lta.app.cron.tms.TMSInboundCSVImportCron.cronAction(TMSInboundCSVImportCron.java:193) 
at psdi.server.CronTaskManager.callCronMethod(CronTaskManager.java:2414) 
at psdi.server.CronTaskManager.access$1100(CronTaskManager.java:104) 
at psdi.server.CronTaskManager$CronThread.run(CronTaskManager.java:3305) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:482) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:273)
```

The code that is trying to do the download is:

```
Vector<LsEntry> vtFiles = sftpBean.listFile(SFTPFolder);
if (vtFiles != null) { 
    for (LsEntry lsEntry : vtFiles) { 
        String csvFile = lsEntry.getFilename(); 
        System.out.println(lsEntry.getFilename() + "\r\n"); 
        blResult = sftpBean.downloadFile(csvFile, processFolder);
```

I am also providing path as per Linux for example:

- Source path is `/Ab/LTA/`. From where I am downloading file.
- Destination path  is `/Ab/ABC/`. From where I want to download.

Comment: source path looks to be a directory, not a file?

Comment: Yes I am listing all the files and putting it in  a variable and calling  get method...it  is working when I try to do the same in 2 windows machine.

Comment: All the files under the source path is listed and passed in variable

SFTPFolder is my source ,it is a variable where I am storing my source path.

Vector<LsEntry> vtFiles = sftpBean.listFile(SFTPFolder);

     if (vtFiles != null) {

      for (LsEntry lsEntry : vtFiles) {
       String csvFile = lsEntry.getFilename();
       System.out.println(lsEntry.getFilename() + "\r\n");
       blResult = sftpBean.downloadFile(csvFile,
         processFolder);

Comment: Try with `String csvFile = SFTPFolder + "/" + lsEntry.getFilename();`

Comment: I had similar problem and String csvFile = SFTPFolder + "/" + lsEntry.getFilename(); solved my problem, thanks